# Updating column on comparing of two rows value from same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to format my result into the following:

```
ID    pred  probability cost  
101   1     0.15        0.9  
101   2     0.85        0.1  
102   2     0.25        0.55  
102   1     0.75        0.44
```

The required format is to get result column on the basis of higher probability for e.g., for `ID` 101 the probability of `pred` value '2' is higher so result column will have '2' as value for `ID` '101' :

```
ID    result  pred  cost  
101   2       1     0.9  
101   2       2     0.1  
102   1       2     0.55  
102   1       1     0.44
```

I tried getting the max `probability` by grouping on basis of `ID` like:

```
SELECT  
   ID,  
    MAX(probability) prob  
FROM  
    table  
GROUP BY  
    ID
```

and concatenating the other rows on basis of `ID` and `probability` like:

```
with temp as (  
SELECT  
        ID,  
        MAX(probability) prob  
    FROM  
        table  
    GROUP BY  
        ID  
)  
select id,
base.ID, base.pred, base.cost
from base
where temp.ID = base.ID and base.probability = temp.prob
```

but not getting the expected output. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with s  (ID, pred, probability, cost) as (
select 101,   1,     0.15,        0.9  from dual union all
select 101,   2,     0.85,        0.1  from dual union all
select 102,   2,     0.25,        0.55 from dual union all
select 102,   1,     0.75,        0.44 from dual)
select
s.*,
nth_value(pred, 1) ignore nulls over (partition by id order by probability desc) nth
from s
order by id, probability;

        ID       PRED PROBABILITY       COST        NTH
---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
       101          1         .15         .9          2
       101          2         .85         .1          2
       102          2         .25        .55          1
       102          1         .75        .44          1
```

Answer (score 1):

use `last_value` function

```
LAST_VALUE(pred) IGNORE NULLS
         OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY probability ROWS BETWEEN
           UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS result
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ee98b31446a263a680a01617cabe50d0)

Answer (score 0):

use window function

```
 with cte as

(
select 101 as id, 1 as pred, 0.15 as pro, 0.9 as cost from dual
union all
select 101,2,0.85,0.1 from dual
union all
select 102,2,0.25,0.55 from dual
union all
select 102,1,0.75,.44 from dual
)
, cte1 as
(
select t.*,  max(pro) over(partition by ID) as result
from cte t
) select cte1.id,cte.pred as result,cte1.pred,cte1.cost 
from cte1 left join cte on cte1.result=cte.pro
 order by cte1.ID,cte1.cost desc,cte1.pred
```

output

```
    ID  RESULT  PRED    COST
   101      2     1     .9
   101      2     2     .1
   102      1     2     .55
   102      1     1     .44
```